# VAE active units

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders, generative-models

According to [Burda et al (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00519.pdf) number of active units is computed as:
$ Cov_x(E_{z \sim q_\phi(z|x)}) > \delta $

for some particular delta. In the paper it is set to 0.02 empirically. But this only measures units in vector z that are mostly constant. Another way of prior collapse for VAE is random units in z, i.e. - units that are independent from input *x* and those that decoder part of VAE learns to ignore. Is there a way to measure it?

One way I can think of is to set units in *z* to random value and measure its effect on decoded input. But this is rather slow process for high-dimensional *z*. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A latent unit $z_i$ having low covariance with $x$ doesn't mean that  $z_i$ is constant, it means it varies independently of $x$, i.e. $p(x,z_i) = p(x)p(z_i)\ ^{**}$. Simple proof:

$$\text{Covar}(x, z_i) 
= \int_{x,z} \!\!\!p(x,z) (x-\bar{x})(z - \bar{z}) 
\ \overset{**}{=} 
\int_{x,z} \!\!\!p(x)p(z) (x-\bar{x})(z - \bar{z}) \\\qquad\quad\ \ = 
\int_{x} p(x)(x-\bar{x}) \int_zp(z) (z - \bar{z}) = 
(\bar{x}-\bar{x}) (\bar{z} - \bar{z}) = 0$$

So low covariance (*not* variance) identifies $z$ components that are independent of $x$, i.e. carry no information, or are "dead" from a useful representation perspective.

The same measure is used when considering *posterior collapse* (e.g. [in Variational Autoencoders (VAEs)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.05534.pdf)), which refers to when **all** dimensions of $z$ are independent of $x$.